# Run pre-requisite tasks before anything else in GNU Make?

Tags: gnu-make

I've got a Makefile with targets like this:

```
all: a b

a: a_prereqs a_steps
b: b_prereqs b_steps
```

`a` and `b` take a while to run and have prerequisites. I'd like both `a_prereqs` and `b_prereqs` to run first (so that I don't have to wait for `a_steps` to complete before discovering that `b_steps` will fail.

But I don't want `b_prereqs` to run *unless* I'm running `b`.

How can I do this in GNU Make?

Answer (score 0):

```
all: a b

a: a_steps
b: b_steps

a_steps: a_prereqs
b_steps: b_prereqs
```

And then run make with more jobs

```
$ make -j X
```